# image not taking the full height of the container

Tags: html, css

I was creating the about section of my site and was placing an image besides some text and now when i shrink the screen size the image for some reason is not taking up the full height of the containing `<div>`.. please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9j61oua/9/) and help me understand the reason for this.

The borders will show you the gap at the bottom which I don't want to show..

Please note that I do have bootstrap wired in as well for the project but I am not using it for this section.

Thanking all of you in anticipation

Answer (score 3):

img tag is inline-block by default, so you need something like this:

```
.about-content img {
    display: block; /* remove extra space below image */
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: will not keep aspect ratio

Answer (score 2):

You've got min-width and max-width set on the images's parent, as follows:

```
.about-content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: calc(50% - 2em);
}
```

Remove the min / max width properties and it works (note, I've added a media query in the CSS as per below): https://jsfiddle.net/m9j61oua/7/

Although pretty pointless as I don't know any devices that go that small, you could wrap it in a media query :

```
@media (min-width: 201px) {
    .about-content {
        min-width: 200px;
        max-width: calc(50% - 2em);
    }
}
```

EDIT - Further to comments below, I think the only way forward for you is to use a background-image on the second div, here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m9j61oua/14/

Relevant CSS:

```
.about-content.bg-image {
  background-image: url(http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/1620/images/carousel_small/bengal-tiger-why-matter_7341043.jpg?1345548942);
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

I've appended the class `bg-image` to your second div and removed the image element within it.

As you can see, it's not a perfect solution to what you're looking for, but with the right image and some media queries, you should be able to crack it.

Comment: David please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m9j61oua/9/ , I want the text section and the image section to be of the same height which will be evident from this fiddle as i have given borders to the containers and this is where the problem is , the more I shrink the window the gap at the bottom increases

Comment: @DhavalChheda I must've misread the question and assumed I knew what you meant rather than what you described. My mistake, I'll look into revising my answer.

Comment: @DhavalChheda Please check revised EDIT above.

Answer (score 1):

The image isn't any higher. If you give it `height: auto`, it keeps its proportions, which usually is desired.

If you would set it to height:100%, it would be distorted, or (if you then set width to "auto") cut off a the sides.

One possibility would be to define the image as background image for its container and use `background-size: cover; background-position: center; Background-repeat: no-repeat;` on it. But this will cut off some parts of the image.

If you use `background-size: contain;`instead, you get the full image again, but with some space on either the sides or top and bottom.

Comment: I have set the height to auto and then used this selector .image-box {
    background-image: url('images/tower.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
} but it has the same height issue and the image is also repeating..

Answer (score 0):

You have defined such style

```
.about-content img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

which force browser to keep image aspect ratio.

Use image with correct aspect ratio or change style of img element.

Comment: i tried height : 100% and max-height: 100% but no go so can you please provide an example of what else may be tried..

Comment: .about-content img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
} seems to work : https://jsfiddle.net/qkcoggzx/

Comment: You must to choose correct image for such component. Using wide image in this case is not good idea

Comment: please refer to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qkcoggzx/1/ , I want the image to cover the full container..

Answer (score -1):

There is a little change on line #14 in css. change `max-width: 100%;` to `max-width: auto;` `height:auto` to `height:100%` & 
And Here is your code Make changes in your css and it will work. :

```
.about-content-wrapper {
    margin: 2em 0 5em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 1em;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.about-content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: calc(50% - 2em);
}
.about-content img {
    max-width: none;
    height: 100%;
}
.about-content h2,
.about-content p {
    margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
}
```